# How to "run" a wpf user control ro check on its behaviour?

Tags: wpf

In Blend (4), how can I "run" a wpf user control ?
I'm trying to implement some animations at the moment and have no clue how to "run" my user controls to debug the behaviour of those.

There isnt any obvious "run" button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to set up a separate project in your solution to do that. As long as your UserControls do not depend on other (external) controls i.e. their coupling is going towards zero you can instantiate them in a plain project to test them.

I am calling these test-projects Prototype-Grounds and and at least for me it is an efficient and effective way to test UserControls.

Hope I could give you an idea :)

Comment: Sounds like an acceptable solution, although I hope there is better ;) Anyway, I've created a WPF application project in the same solution as my WPF library, added a project reference to the library, but then, I don't see where I get to drop my controls on the frame.. :)

Comment: If you find the "run" button you've initially asked for, please let me know ;) Right now I am having no Visual Studio at hand, but don't you have to include your UserControls in the Toolbox panel inside Studio somehow via checking the category "External Controls" or "UserControls" (maybe with a right-click onto the toolbox) ?

Comment: Still looking. Btw I am trying all of this in Blend 4, not doing anything with Visual Studio yet.

Comment: In Blend4 you can open your "Assets" panel. There you have a submenu called "Controls" where you can look for your controls ...

Answer (score 0):

In your `App.xaml` in the RootObject `Application` replace the value of the attribute `StartupUri` by the path of your `UserControl`.

Example :

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
         StartupUri="Views/Test/MyUserControl.xaml">
<!--StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">-->
```